# Speech Recognition simple example on Android in Codename One

Tags: android, speech-recognition, codenameone

I want to be able to integrate Speech Recognition in Codename One apps when using Android, so I decided to create a small example. Here is what I did:

I created a new app and then I then followed [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/KgskSDk98Ts), so I created an interface for native access:

```
public interface SpeechRecognition extends NativeInterface {
   void startListening();
   String getResult();
}
```

The main form looks like this:

```
    SpeechRecognition speechRecognition = NativeLookup.create(SpeechRecognition.class);

    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    Button startButton = new Button("start");
    Button stopButton = new Button("stop");
    Label label = new Label("non");
    startButton.addActionListener(event -> {
        if (speechRecognition != null && speechRecognition.isSupported()) {
            speechRecognition.startListening();
        }
    });

    stopButton.addActionListener(event -> {
        if (speechRecognition != null && speechRecognition.isSupported()) {
            label.setText(speechRecognition.getResult());
        }
    });
    hi.addComponent(startButton);
    hi.addComponent(stopButton);
    hi.addComponent(label);
    hi.show();
```

Basically I want whenever I click "start", the speech recognition to start listening, and when stop - to update the label with the recognized result. Then I generated native access and in the android implementation I used the following:

```
public class SpeechRecognitionImpl {
//maybe use a getter for message to get the last event
static String message = "";
static String speech = "";
private SpeechRecognizer sr;

public void startListening() {
    //initialize the Intent

    final Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
    //number of guesses
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
    //Speechrecognition must be run on main Thread

    Activity activity = AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity());
            sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());
            sr.startListening(intent);
        }
    });
}


public String getResult() {
    return speech;
}

public boolean isSupported() {
    return true;
}

class listener implements RecognitionListener {

    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        message = "onReadyForSpeech";
    }

    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        message =  "onBeginningOfSpeech";
    }

    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        message =  "onRmsChanged";
    }

    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        message =  "onBufferReceived";
    }

    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        message =  "onEndofSpeech";
    }

    public void onError(int error) {
        message =  "error " + error;
    }

    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        //here you have what google understand from the speech
        //maybe only save the first guess, which would have the highest
        //possibility
        speech += "on results";
        String str = "";

        ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

            str += data.get(i)+";";
        }
        speech += str;
    }

    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        message =  "onPartialResults";

    }

    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

        message =  "onEvent " + eventType;
    }
}
```

This is basically copy pasted the example that "should" work. However, when I run it on my Android app, absolutely nothing happens. Has anyone had success with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the app with DDMS and look at the logs of the app. I'm guessing you just missed adding a permission to the manifest using the build hints.

Comment: Adding build hint 
android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
solved the problem.